# ClassCastException when using LinearLayout.LayoutParams

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

This is the exception:

```
07-20 19:52:14.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3908): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-20 19:52:14.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3908): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams
07-20 19:52:14.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3908):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:634)
07-20 19:52:14.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3908):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
07-20 19:52:14.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3908):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12892)
07-20 19:52:14.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3908):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
07-20 19:52:14.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3908):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
07-20 19:52:14.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3908):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12892)
07-20 19:52:14.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3908):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1249)
07-20 19:52:14.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3908):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12892)
07-20 19:52:14.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3908):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
07-20 19:52:14.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3908):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
07-20 19:52:14.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3908):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12892)
07-20 19:52:14.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3908):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
07-20 19:52:14.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3908):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
07-20 19:52:14.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3908):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12892)
07-20 19:52:14.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3908):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
07-20 19:52:14.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3908):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
07-20 19:52:14.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3908):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2265)
07-20 19:52:14.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3908):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12892)
07-20 19:52:14.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3908):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1240)
07-20 19:52:14.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3908):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2628)
07-20 19:52:14.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3908):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-20 19:52:14.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3908):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-20 19:52:14.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3908):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
07-20 19:52:14.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3908):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-20 19:52:14.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3908):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-20 19:52:14.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3908):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
07-20 19:52:14.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3908):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
07-20 19:52:14.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3908):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I can't see a line where the exception is thrown so I can't figure it out quite good. I do know it is in these lines:

```
public class TodayFragment extends Fragment {

ListView listView;
String[] urls;
ActionBar mActionBar;
Spinner spinner1;

public TodayFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LinearLayout linear = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    linear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    spinner1 = new Spinner(getActivity());
    spinner1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    linear.addView(spinner1);
    listView = new ListView(getActivity());
    spinner1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    linear.addView(listView);

    new ParseHTML().execute();
    return linear;
    }
}
```

The fragment I'm using is android.support.v4.app.Fragment. What causes this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your import statement for LayoutParams is probably importing ViewGroup.LayoutParams.  Try explicitly using LinearLayout.LayoutParams(...):

```
   spinner1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
           LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
           LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting LinearLayout's LayoutParams' before attatching any children.

```
LinearLayout linear = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
linear.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
linear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you're wondering which LayoutParams you must use for each View, look at this [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#layout-params) :

Each view must have a LayoutParam acording to his parent.

For example, in order to create this Views hierarhy,

- RelativeLayout relativeLayout

  - LinearLayout linearLayout , orientation: vertical
  - TextView textView
  - Button button1
  - Button button2

replace the content of your onCreate method in your main activity with :

```
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

  LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
  linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
  linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
  relativeLayout.addView(linearLayout);

  TextView textView = new TextView(this);
  textView.setText("a text");
  textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
  linearLayout.addView(textView);

  Button button1 = new Button(this);
  button1.setText("button 1");
  button1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
  linearLayout.addView(button1);

  setContentView(relativeLayout);
```