# LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams

Tags: android

**Explanation and solution at the bottom.**

I am developing one slider layout animation, the animation work fine but when all processes end, they get next Exception.

I guess `RelativeLayout` parent have something to do in exception, but I don't know how to resolve it.

```
09-06 11:24:58.952: E/Trace(30884): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-06 11:25:09.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30884): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-06 11:25:09.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30884): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams
09-06 11:25:09.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:311)
09-06 11:25:09.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15264)
09-06 11:25:09.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4916)
09-06 11:25:09.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
09-06 11:25:09.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15264)
09-06 11:25:09.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4916)
09-06 11:25:09.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
09-06 11:25:09.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
09-06 11:25:09.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
09-06 11:25:09.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15264)
09-06 11:25:09.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4916)
09-06 11:25:09.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
09-06 11:25:09.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2161)
09-06 11:25:09.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15264)
09-06 11:25:09.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2129)
09-06 11:25:09.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1240)
09-06 11:25:09.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1433)
09-06 11:25:09.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1125)
09-06 11:25:09.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4607)
09-06 11:25:09.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:747)
09-06 11:25:09.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:567)
09-06 11:25:09.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:536)
09-06 11:25:09.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:733)
09-06 11:25:09.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-06 11:25:09.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-06 11:25:09.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
09-06 11:25:09.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
09-06 11:25:09.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-06 11:25:09.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-06 11:25:09.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
09-06 11:25:09.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
09-06 11:25:09.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

activity_home.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/leftView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#cad000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#876000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#cecece"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSlide"
                style="@style/btn1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="X" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    UserStorage userStorage = new UserStorage();

    private Button btnSlide;
    private LinearLayout mainView, leftView;
    private SliderAnimation slideAnimation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        this.leftView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.leftView);
        this.mainView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainView);

        this.btnSlide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSlide);
        this.btnSlide.setOnClickListener(this);

        this.slideAnimation = new SliderAnimation(this);

        this.slideAnimation.initializeFilterAnimations(this.mainView, this.leftView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.btnSlide:

            this.slideAnimation.toggleLeftSliding();

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

AnimationListener

```
public class SliderAnimation implements AnimationListener {

    private Context context;

    private LinearLayout mainView, leftView;

    private Animation mainSlideIn, mainSlideOut;

    private boolean leftAnimated, rightAnimated = false;

    private int deviceWidth;

    public SliderAnimation(Context context) {

        this.context = context;

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources()
                .getDisplayMetrics();

        this.deviceWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    }

    public void initializeFilterAnimations(LinearLayout mainView,
            LinearLayout leftView) {

        this.mainView = mainView;
        this.leftView = leftView;

        this.mainSlideIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
                R.anim.main_slide_in);
        this.mainSlideIn.setAnimationListener(this);

        this.mainSlideOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
                R.anim.main_slide_out);
        this.mainSlideOut.setAnimationListener(this);
    }

    public void toggleLeftSliding() {

        if (!this.leftAnimated) {

            this.mainView.startAnimation(this.mainSlideIn);
        } else {

            this.mainView.startAnimation(this.mainSlideOut);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

        if (!this.leftAnimated) {

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    (this.deviceWidth * 20) / 100, this.mainView.getHeight());

            params.leftMargin = (this.deviceWidth * 80) / 100;

            this.mainView.setLayoutParams(params);

            this.leftAnimated = true;
        } else {

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    this.deviceWidth, this.mainView.getHeight());

            params.leftMargin = 0;

            this.mainView.setLayoutParams(params);

            this.leftAnimated = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

**EXPLANATION AND SOLUTION**

We've to know the parent ViewGroup container for the view, because views are filled with their parent LayoutParams for measure purposes.

If we don't know through a simple glance on the xml which is the parent ViewGroup for the View, we can get always its reference with .getParent() method from the View instance.

Comment: This is the correct answer <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045360/getting-classcastexception-when-trying-to-insert-relativelayout-dyanmically/10046252#10046252>?

Answer (score 146):

I ran into a similar problem and I found [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10046252/62921). Basically, you should choose the LayoutParams depending on the parent, in your case `new LinearLayout.LayoutParams` should be `new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`.

Comment: Nice to know, you solved my issue, I was trying to add the constraint on the child instead of the parent. Now it's working like a charm.

Comment: Ohhh.. the PARENT. Makes sense. Was setting it based on its own type, which was a ViewGroup of a different kind (ie: LinearLayout where parent was FrameLayout). Subtle!

Answer (score 17):

You should not make the `LayoutParmas` object of the layout whose dimension you want to set from java. Rather you should make the `LayoutParams` object of the parent layout. For example in the layout below to set the layout params of the `LinearLayout` you have to make the `LayoutParmas` of `RelativeLayout` not `LinearLayout` itself:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".newsblog.NewsDetailsActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In activity class:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(30,30); // parent params
linearLayout.setLayoutParmas(params); // child layout
```

If you want to set the params of the `RelativeLayout`, it seems it doesn't have any parent but it has a parent created by android framework which is a frame layout:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParmas params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParmas(30, 30); // FrameLayout is a parent-created by android framework
relativeLayout.setLayoutParmas(params); // relative layout is child here
```

Comment: This is the right answer. I changed RelativeLayout.LayoutParams to FrameLayout.LayoutParams then the problem was solved.

Answer (score 9):

Try doing a clean of your project. You must have copy pasted a block of xml from a FrameLayout and changed the tag. This is a nasty bug in android.

There was a similar issue on another discussion. I hope this is the same cause.

Comment: What I must to do exactly?, 1º Cut which code bit?. 2º clean project and after paste the cut code bit again?

Comment: On your Eclipse menu: Project -> Clean... Just re run your app. That error should go away.

Comment: Hi again @Chad, your solution not work, same error persist... :(

Comment: Sir, I tried re-creating your app based on your code but commented out initializeFilterAnimations() because you didn't provide the codes for those and your app worked perfectly fine. so i think you never rebuilt your application like i said.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(this.mainview.getWidth(),       this.mainview.getHeight());
  params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
  this.mainview.setLayoutParams(params);
```

This may be help.

Comment: Thank you for your interest, but not work, get same exception.

Comment: LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) this.mainview.getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
     this.mainview.setLayoutParams(params);

Comment: check link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584900/classcastexception-when-using-linearlayout-layoutparams

Comment: Nothing... Some error with your approach. I saw that link before, but is other case with same exception.

Comment: i guess u have declare another layout with same name.

Comment: Name or type, I guess might declare all layouts as RelativeLayout I not have problem, but I think is no good solution. I want to know reason and resolve it.

Comment: When you are giving <left, top, right, bottom> in setMargins, why is there a need for width and height ? How can I avoid it  ?

Answer (score 2):

Above error due to passing wrong casting params :- 
because some time you set programattically parameter for linear layout but when you doing getLayoutParams() then it some time gives parent layout reference then it is gives above error .

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) parentLayout.getLayoutParams();
        int leftMargin = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.exclusion_card_margin_left_right);
        int rightMargin = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.exclusion_card_margin_left_right);

        params.setMargins(leftMargin, 0, rightMargin, 0);
        parentLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```